# How to call instance methods inside a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to call instance methods inside a block. Here is the method that I am working with,

```
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [self myInstanceMethod];
}];
```

But I am not able to reference self from inside this block. What should I do?

**EDIT**: I am sorry that I posted this question in a hurry. Actually I was getting a ***warning*** (*Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle*) with this approach.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `self` directly inside a block may cause a retain cycle, to avoid a retain cycle you should create a weak reference to self and then use that reference inside the block to call your instance methods. Use the below code to call instance methods inside a block

```
__weak YourViewController * weakSelf = self;
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [weakSelf myInstanceMethod];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
__block YourViewController *blockSafeSelf = self;    
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [blockSafeSelf myInstanceMethod];
}];
```

_block will retain self, so you can also use a _weak reference :

```
YourViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;
 [self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
        [weakSelf myInstanceMethod];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

```
__block YourViewController *blockInstance = self;  
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [blockInstance myInstanceMethod];
}];
```

**Note :** However, that the block will retain self. If you end up storing this block in an ivar, you could easily create a retain cycle, which means neither would ever get deallocated.

To avoid this problem, it’s best practice to capture a weak reference to self, like this:

```
__weak YourViewController *weakSelf = self;
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [weakSelf myInstanceMethod];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call instance method inside a block  .
you could try the below code and it's  suggested by apple 
and here is a link for https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/AcquireBasicProgrammingSkills/AcquireBasicSkills/AcquireBasicSkills.html

```js
__block typeof(self) tmpSelf = self;
[self.someVariable addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:timeArray queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
    [tmpSelf myInstanceMethod];
}];

For example
//References to self in blocks

__block typeof(self) tmpSelf = self;
[self methodThatTakesABlock:^ {
    [tmpSelf doSomething];
}];
```